# list function on generator deletes elements

Tags: python, iterator, generator, sympy, iterable

I don't understand why the code below deletes all elements. How can I prevent it?

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import variations
x=variations(["H","T"],3, True)
print(list(x))

t=sum(1 for i in x)
print(list(x))
```

Comment: if variations returns a generator and then you print it using `list` you consume all the elements, so don't print it if you want to keep it

Comment: @aws_apprentice so `sum(1 for i in x)` consumes elements too? `for` function too? How can this be prevented so that I can first find the number fo elements in the list and then thread over it with `for` loop multiple times.

Comment: How can I do it efficiently when the generator has large number of elements?

Comment: yes any operation on a generator consumes it. if you need to use a certain amount of numbers from it then save those to a separate data structure and use that.

Comment: Work with `x = list(x)` the list produced by the generator.  `itertools` has functions like `tee` that replicate iterators.  But I'm not sure that will make your code any more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Generators can be consumed, which is what's happening in line 3, `print(list(x))`. One way to fix this is to save it as a list, though maybe there's a more appropriate solution in this case.

```
y = list(x)
print(y)
t = len(y)  # Since y is a list, we can use len
print(y)
```

Also note you can reproduce this behaviour with any generator. Sympy is beside the point.

Comment: Thanks for the response. May I ask you to have a look at the comments I posted above?

Comment: @AlGuy Sure. Firstly, there's no way to get the number of elements in a generator without iterating over it, which exhausts it. Secondly, IMO efficiency is another topic, so you could ask a new question about that.